# IntelliJ Idea structural search for implementations of all imported interface

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I hava a JAVA (+ Spring) project with three modules: A, B and C.
Module A and module B depends of module C, but they don't depends of each other. C has some interfaces which are implemented in module A or module B. Can I use structural search for searching for all Java classes which are in A, and implement's an interface from C, which is used in B? Is it some tool in Idea which can list me these classes?

E.g.:
Module A:

```
class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
}
class MyNonImpl {
}
```

Module B:

```
interface MyInterface {
}
```

module C:

```
import mypackage.MyInterface;
class MyClass {
}
```

The search expression should find MyInterfaceImpl in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> (Find usages) while having cursor on the interface will find all usages of that interface - all classes which implement it even across modules.

> Usages in extends/implements clause.

[image]